# Kotlin: structure for sequential coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-coroutines

I am building a library manager app for Android and am trying to build a view to show the hierarchy of "collections" (i.e. folders) from the current collection up to root.

The database is implemented with Room (accessed indirectly via the collectionRepo). Each Collection object has a unique key and knows its parent's key.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Given the current collection's key, build the Collection hierarchy
   up to root.
2. After this is complete, build a UI rendering of the
   hierarchy.

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward with Kotlin's coroutines, but I haven't been able to get the coroutines structured correctly.

Since each call to `collectionRepo.getCollection(curKey)` ultimately does a Room db query, it has to be off the main thread. But I need to wait for the query to return in order to know the parentKey needed for the subsequent query.

```
private suspend fun buildBackstackView() {

    var curKey = collectionViewModel.getCurrentCollectionKey()

    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            do {
                val curCollection = when (curKey) {
                    "" -> {
                        Collection("", 0, "TOP", "") // collection's parent is root - create a fake root Collection to push to the stack
                    }
                    else -> {
                        collectionRepo.getCollection(curKey) // ultimately a Room database query
                    }
                }

                collectionStack.add(curCollection)
                curKey = curCollection.key

            } while (curKey != "")
        }
    }

    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {

        ...build UI view using collectionStack...

    }
}
```

In response to Sergey's request, collectionRepo.getCollection() just passes the request along to a DAO method that defines a Room query.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM collections WHERE `key` = :colKey LIMIT 1")
fun getCollection(colKey: String): Collection
```

Comment: Could you also add definition of `collectionRepo.getCollection()` method please, and what is `coroutineScope`?

Comment: I added code for the method call. coroutineScope is from kotlinx https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#structured-concurrency

Answer (score 0):

Please check next code, it should help you:

```
    // creating local scope for coroutines
    private var job: Job = Job()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)     

    // call this to cancel job when you don't need it anymore, for example in Activity.onDestroy() method
    fun cancelJob() {
        job.cancel()
    }

    private fun buildBackstackView() {
        var curKey = collectionViewModel.getCurrentCollectionKey()

        scope.launch {
            do {
                val curCollection = when (curKey) {
                    "" -> {
                        Collection("", 0, "TOP", "")
                    }
                    else -> withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // runs in background thread suspending the coroutine
                        collectionRepo.getCollection(curKey)
                    }

                }

                collectionStack.add(curCollection)
                curKey = curCollection.key

            } while (curKey != "")

            // ...build UI view using collectionStack...
        }
    }
```

To use **Dispatchers.Main** import:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'
```

Comment: Closer than I was, but it still is not working. `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` does not seem to be suspending the coroutine. This code sets up a race condition where the order of the collection stack is completely random from one execution to the next (if the stack builds at all).

Comment: According to the docs of `withContext()` function: `Calls the specified suspending block with a given coroutine context, suspends until it completes, and returns the result.` it should suspend the coroutine.